# how to configure Two cornjob kubernetes in the same file

Tags: kubernetes

i have cornjob and i need to add another cornjob in the same file

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: cronjob-ONESHOP-5180
  namespace: bose-production
spec:
  schedule: "0 7 * * *" for runing the job every day at 7 AM
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            env:
            -name:bose-production
      
              -commande:["drush auto_depublication:terminaux"]          
              
              #//Lancer la commande Drush ops
              args:
                - /bin/sh
                - '-c'
                - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure


apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: cronjob-ONESHOP-5180
  namespace: bose-production
spec:
  schedule: "0 7 * * *" for runing the job every day at 7 AM
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            env:
            -name:bose-production
      
              -commande:["drush auto_depublication:terminaux"]          
              
              #//Lancer la commande Drush ops
              args:
                - /bin/sh
                - '-c'
                - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Comment: can you format your question to better understand?

Answer (score -1):

Add a YAML start-of-document marker before the second CronJob.  This is `---` on its own line.

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: first
...
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: second
...
```

Standard Kubernetes tools like `kubectl apply -f` and Helm understand multi-document YAML files just fine.  The two documents are separate Kubernetes objects, so you need to make sure they have different names or namespaces, and all of the required fields appear in both documents.

(These tools also understand directories, and you could also create the second CronJob in a second file.)